# Multithreading concept

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am learning multi-threading concepts now. I can run a single thread with the help of handler and Runnable(). I want my code to run two threads, say Thread1 runs method1() and thread2 runs method2(). Thread1 should run for 2seconds and then sleep for 1second. In the mean time, thread2 should wakeup and run for 1second. Again, thread1 should run for 2seconds. This process should be done continuously. I am doing this in Android.

The question might look straight forward, but I have no other way, other than posting a question here, as I have gone through many tutorials and questions in this website. No post suits my context. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use timer and timertask to achieve this

Comment: How can I make it? Any sample code please..

Comment: Doesn't having two threads which sleep at alternate times seems to defeat the point of having two threads? Perhaps you will get an answer more related to threading if you give an example of what each thread should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, with which you can achieve parallel execution of your tasks. A small sample example to schedule the tasks:

```
//creates a thread pool of size 2
int poolSize = 2;
// creates ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor object with number of thread 2
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize);

//starts executing after 1 second
ScheduledFuture<Callable-Type> sf = stpe.schedule(new TaskOne(), 1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//starts executing after 2 seconds
ScheduledFuture<Callable-Type> sf1 = stpe.schedule(new TaskTwo(), 2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And you can define your tasks as below:

```
class TaskOne implements Callable<Callable-Type> {
    @Override
    public Callable-Type call() throws Exception {
        //DO YOUR WORK HERE
        return callable-type;
    }
}

class TaskTwo implements Callable<Callable-Type> {
        @Override
        public Callable-Type call() throws Exception {
            //DO YOUR WORK HERE
            return callable-type;
        }
    }
```

The advantages of using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` over `Timer` are :

- A Timer creates only a single thread for executing timer tasks. Scheduled 
  thread pools address this limitation by letting you provide multiple threads for executing deferred and periodic tasks.
- Another problem with Timer is that it behaves poorly if a TimerTask throws an unchecked exception. The Timer thread doesn't catch the exception, so an unchecked exception thrown from a TimerTask terminates the timer thread.

Ref: **Java Concurrency in Practice**

Comment: Thank you @Debojit Saikia, for your reply and sorry for my late reply. I have a doubt, both the threads I want to run are UI Threads implementing image slideshow. I want to use sleep(),notify() methods for that. Can you please explain me, how your code relates this issue?

Comment: @nki Both the threads(T1,T2) will work on the same object(O1), so that any of them (suppose T1)can wait for a specific condition to become true. And when the other thread(T2) calls `notifyAll` after changing the object's state, the waiting thread(T1) should wake up and start working - Is this your requirement? Sorry I got confused about the issue.

Comment: when t1 runs for 2sec and then sleeps for 1sec. t2 runs in that mean time means, t2 runs for 1 sec and sleeps for 2sec. this is some what related to concurrency concept.

Comment: It seems threads T1 and T2 do not run concurrently. They run one after another. I think this can be solved with a single thread of execution, making the thread to do work W1 for 2 sec and then work W2 for 1 sec. You can put this in a `while` loop to repeat this execution cycle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Sample**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //your code
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 2000, 1000); // 2000 is delay and 1000 is call period
```

There is also another schedule() methods that you can use to map your criteria.